# Pointer Cursor not showing

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS for this. I have a custom upload image button on my page

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div className='upload-btn-wrapper'>
  <a onClick={this.changePageImage}>Change Image</a>
  <input type='file' name='page_photo' onChange={this.photoChangeHandler} />
</div>
```

My question is why is the pointer cursor not showing up when I hover over the wrapper? I noticed there is a tiny sweet spot in the bottom left hand corner of the a tag but it's just in the one tiny spot.

I've even tried this

```
.upload-btn-wrapper a:hover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do here but the issue is that in HTML there is no ClassName... it should be class="upload-btn-wrapper". Basically your class is never applied.

Comment: @NawedKhan Please read the question completely. I'm using ReactJS, this is not plain HTML. className compiles to class. Even though I didn't specify that I'm using ES6 in my JS files it's pretty typical to see className when using ReactJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file]` Is set to `position: absolute;` And is therefore containing the whole `upload-btn-wrapper` block. In other words, your anchor is behind the input that is absolute positioned, so you are unable to hover over it.

You can add `z-index` to the anchor tag to move it up a step, or move the input behind using negative `z-index`.

Comment: There is the additional issue that position absolute leads to the absolute positioned element to fill no space in the outer one, so it shrinks to the smallest possible size excluding the absolute positioned one, making it rather small...

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. I just used z-index: -1